# What's the best way to add/remove classes from all li element of ul element in angular 6?

Tags: angular

I am trying to find best way to write less code to achieve removing css class of all `<li>` elements of `<ul>` element when user click on a li that should be selected and remove all others..

I think so far this is the solution in angular 6

```
<li [ngClass]="{'active': selectedItem === 'item1'}" (click)="selectedItem = 'item1'"></li>
<li [ngClass]="{'active': selectedItem === 'item2'}" (click)="selectedItem = 'item2'"></li>
```

Regards,
Manoj

Comment: One simplest syntax would be : `[class.active]="selectedItem === 'item1'"`. But if you want to make it really simple, use or create a custom component that is doing what you want.

Comment: @ibenjelloun's answer will work. As well as yours approach has no issues.

Answer (score -1):

### You can leverage the `ElementRef`

```
<li [ngClass]="{'active': selectedItem === ele1}" #ele1 (click)="selectedItem = ele1"></li>
<li [ngClass]="{'active': selectedItem === ele2}" #ele2 (click)="selectedItem = ele2"></li>
```